# How to download highlighted text on Kobo Aura HD?

Tags: kobo

I often highlight words that I don't know on my Kobo Aura HD, so that I can come back to them later. Is there any way for me to download the list of highlighted words onto my computer? A file on the Kobo filesystem that I can parse?

Comment: You can do this with [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) as far as I know. Might have to install the [Kobo Utilities plugin](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=215339) first, though. [This script might work](http://www.albertopettarin.it/exportnotes.html), too, but I don't know if it has been updated lately. I would write a proper answer, but I haven't tested any of these solutions. Here's hoping that someone with more experience will chime in.